# How to push string to typescript array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to push string to typescript array its throwing error `can not push to undefined" , is it correct way or i need to use spread operator ?

api.ts

```
const api: IConfigName = {name: "getKey"};
const Name = "Web";

api.optionalParam.push(Name);
```

IConfig.interface.ts

```
export interface IConfigName {
    name: string;
    optionalParam?: string[];
}
```

Comment: `can not push to undefined` is not a real error, please post the actual error message. Are you seeing a *runtime* JavaScript error, or a *compile-time* TypeScript error? Are you using `strictNullChecks`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize **`optionalParam`** with empty array as follows,

```
api.optionalParam = [];
api.optionalParam.push(Name);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked i need to think again i am working with typescript now :)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this because there is no "optionaParam" defined in your `api` object.

your api object currently has only one other, which is "name"

to fix, you can add optionalParam like such:

```
const api: IConfigName = {name: "getKey", optionalParam:[] };
const Name = "Web";

api.optionalParam.push(Name);
```

this should work, since api now has an optionalParam key, with a type of array.